# SQL Server String Concatenation Oddity/Truncation

Tags: sql-server, string, concatenation, truncation

Have the following query:

```
Select
    'SpO2'      = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, [C120]))),
    'Separator' = '% on .',
    'FiO2'      = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, [C130]))),
    'VALUE'     = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, [C120]))) 
                  + '% on .' 
                  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, [C130])))
From...
```

For a given row, I might have the following:

SpO2 = '96', Separator = '% on .', FiO2 = '97', Value = '9'

Or...

SpO2 = '100', Separator = '% on .', FiO2 = '97', Value = '1'

Obviously, in #1, I'd like '96% on .97' and in #2, I'd like '100% on .97'.

Apparently, it's doing string truncation and only returning the first character for 'VALUE', but why? This is working (I think?) on SQL Server 2008 R2. Current failures are occurring using SSMS 2012. Have I lost my mind?

Comment: Can you show some actual data?

Comment: Also what datatypes are your source fields `c120` and `c130`?

Comment: Have you tried the syntax `SELECT (CONVERT(...) + '% on .' + CONVERT(...)) as 'VALUE' FROM ...`?

Comment: Where does it show just one character per `VALUE`? Is it in your application? Could there be something wrong with the properties of the component displaying the results?

Comment: Data type for both fields is `numeric(8,3)`. I have no control over the source data (if that matters). I don't think the syntax matters ('Value' = ... vs. ... As 'Value'). Only one character (i.e., "bad result") is showing up in my application as well as in the query results pane of SSMS.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, it occurred to me that perhaps the problem was with the string literal I was placing in between the two converted values.

Sure enough, the following seems to solve the problem:

```
Select
    'VALUE'     = CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, [C120]))) 
                  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),'% on .')
                  + CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), CONVERT(INT, CONVERT(FLOAT, [C130])))
From...
```

While this is technically an "answer", I'd sure love someone to explain it to me. Why in the world isn't

```
'% on .'
```

simply understood to be of type `VARCHAR` or at least `CHAR(6)`? Is it something to do with the leading "%"? Does that need to be escaped or something?